# Фильтр значений индекса по условию

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, timestamp

Есть датафрейм в таком виде:

```
                      O     C     L     H
'2022-12-10 10:25:00' 25.0  26.3  24.7  27.3
'2022-12-10 10:26:00' 26.3  19.6  19.5  26.4
'2022-12-10 10:27:00' 19.6  20.5  19.4  20.8
'2022-12-10 10:28:00' 20.5  20.8  20.2  20.5
'2022-12-10 10:29:00' 23.0  25.0  22.1  25.2
'2022-12-10 10:30:00' 25.0  21.0  20.5  25.5 
'2022-12-10 10:31:00' 21.0  19.0  18.3  23.8
'2022-12-10 10:32:00' 19.0  22.0  18.1  22.7
'2022-12-10 10:33:00' 22.0  18.0  17.4  24.6
'2022-12-10 10:34:00' 18.0  23.0  15.1  25.4
'2022-12-10 10:35:00' 23.0  15.0  13.9  23.8
'2022-12-10 10:36:00' 15.0  20.0  14.0  20.5
'2022-12-10 10:37:00' 20.0  21.5  18.4  22.0
```

Собственно, это датафрейм цены акции, за небольшой промежуток времени. Индекс имеет тип `datetime32[ns]` или `DatetimeIndex`, остальные колонки - это цена открытия, закрытия, минимальная цена, максимальная - все стандартно.

Задача в следущем, необходимо отобрать значения цены, которая была в диапазоне каждые 5 минут, т.е., необходимы эти индексы (выделил стрелочкой):

```
                      O     C     L     H
'2022-12-10 10:25:00' 25.0  26.3  24.7  27.3
'2022-12-10 10:26:00' 26.3  19.6  19.5  26.4
'2022-12-10 10:27:00' 19.6  20.5  19.4  20.8
'2022-12-10 10:28:00' 20.5  20.8  20.2  20.5
'2022-12-10 10:29:00' 23.0  25.0  22.1  25.2 <-
'2022-12-10 10:30:00' 25.0  21.0  20.5  25.5 
'2022-12-10 10:31:00' 21.0  19.0  18.3  23.8
'2022-12-10 10:32:00' 19.0  22.0  18.1  22.7
'2022-12-10 10:33:00' 22.0  18.0  17.4  24.6
'2022-12-10 10:34:00' 18.0  23.0  15.1  25.4 <-
'2022-12-10 10:35:00' 23.0  15.0  13.9  23.8
'2022-12-10 10:36:00' 15.0  20.0  14.0  20.5
'2022-12-10 10:37:00' 20.0  21.5  18.4  22.0
```

Вроде бы все просто, бери да отбирай значения методами `period`, `shift` или просто пробежаться по колонке индекса, проверить делиться ли значение минут временного периода на 5 с остатком 4 и добавить это значение в новый датафрейм, в общем получиться результат типа такого:

```
                      O     C     L     H
'2022-12-10 10:29:00' 23.0  25.0  22.1  25.2
'2022-12-10 10:34:00' 18.0  23.0  15.1  25.4
```

Но это не верный результат, так как цена открытия, закрытия, минимальная и максимальная, должна браться не только с индекса, на 5-й минуте, но и с предыдущих 4, которые идут за ним, т.е. должно быть так:

```
                      O     C     L     H
'2022-12-10 10:25:00' 25.0  26.3  24.7  27.3
'2022-12-10 10:26:00' 26.3  19.6  19.5  26.4
'2022-12-10 10:27:00' 19.6  20.5  19.4  20.8
'2022-12-10 10:28:00' 20.5  20.8  20.2  20.5
'2022-12-10 10:29:00' 23.0  25.0  22.1  25.2 <-
# конечный результат должен быть таким:
'2022-12-10 10:29:00' 25.0  25.0  19.4  27.3
```

т.е. мы должны найти индекс и проверить, 5-я ли это минута, если да, то берем срез этого индекса и 4-ре индекса перед ним и мы должны получить из этого среза минимальное значение по колонке `L`, максимальное по колонке `H`, цена открытия должна браться с 0 индекса, в примере он выглядит так:

```
'2022-12-10 10:25:00' 25.0  26.3  24.7  27.3
```

а цена закрытия с последнего:

```
'2022-12-10 10:29:00' 23.0  25.0  22.1  25.2
```

Вопрос состоит в том, как это провернуть, т.е. нужно отфильтровать датафрейм и полученный фильтр перенести на другой, где будут только 5-ти минутные значения, учитывая, что датафрейм состоит из 1,6млн+ строк, пробежаться по индексу через функцию map, apply по условию - выходит не очень приятно по времени(. Уверен существует гениально-элегантное решение, которое уже предусмотрено самим пандосом на этот случай, какое?)

Comment: группируете по 5 минут и делаете агрегацию по колонкам, как вам нужно

Comment: @splash58, не понятно что вы имеете ввиду, сгруппировать можно `groupBy`, не спорю, но как применить такое количество условий, там же не просто сумму посчитать или среднее значение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать так:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset

res = df.resample("5T", ).agg({"O":"first", "C": "last", "L":min, "H":max})
res.index = res.index + to_offset("4T")
```

res:

```
                        O     C     L     H
2022-12-10 10:29:00  25.0  25.0  19.4  27.3
2022-12-10 10:34:00  25.0  23.0  15.1  25.5
2022-12-10 10:39:00  23.0  21.5  13.9  23.8
```

Comment: А почему не resample('5M') - я так понимаю, четыре предыдущие минуты нужны, а не просто строки?

Comment: гениально, как по мне, работает намного быстрее, чем тупой перебор с применением условий

Comment: @splash58, работает и так и так, проверено, нет разницы

Comment: @splash58 "M" - это month. "T" == "min", as per https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects

Comment: @strawdog, он имел ввиду `5min`